# Don't emit until some other observable has emitted, then emit all previous values

Tags: rxjs

I'm looking for a way to buffer values of an observable until some other observable has emitted, but then emit all the previous values. Something like skipUntil, if skipUntil also emitted skipped values as soon as the second observable emitted.

```
--a--b----c-----d---e--- (source)
-----------1------------- (other1)
------------abc-d---e----(desired output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bufferWhen](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/bufferWhen):

```
import { fromEvent, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { bufferWhen } from 'rxjs/operators';

const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const buffered = clicks.pipe(bufferWhen(() =>
  interval(1000 + Math.random() * 4000)
));
buffered.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Thanks, but the second observable only emits once and after the first emission I want to stop buffering and emit normally.
 I think I can solve it with `buffer`, turning the emitted array into an observable using `of`, and concatenating all subsequent emissions, but I feel like there has to be a more concise way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the custom operator I came up with. Not sure if it can be done in a prettier way.

```
export function bufferUntil(stopBufferSignal: Observable<any>) {
    return <T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> => {
        return source.pipe(buffer(stopBufferSignal),
            take(1),
            flatMap(ar => {
                const sourceWithNSkipped$: Observable<T> = source.pipe(skip(ar.length));
                const bufferedItems$: Observable<T> = from(ar);
                return bufferedItems$.pipe(concat(sourceWithNSkipped$))
            }));
    }
}
```